# Rethrowing Exception from Child method to Root method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method calling combo as below:

```
Void MainMethod()
{
    try
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Childmethod_1();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

Childmethod_1()
{
    try
    {
        Childmethod_2();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Report(ex);
    }
}

Childmethod_2()
{
    try
    {
        [Block of Code]
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Report(ex) in the Childmethod_1() is used to log the exception details into Database. If there is an exception occures in the Childmethod_2() whenever 'i' in the MainMethod(): For Loop is 4, will this exception block the rest 6 from the action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `throw` from `Childmethod_2` will be caught by the `catch` from `Childmethod_1` and logged to DB too. That catch block does not throw it again, so the exception will not be seen in your main loop, which will not be interrupted.

By the way,

```
catch(ex)
{
  throw ex;
}
```

isn't only bad practice, it's completely useless. Why not just let the exception happen? Furthermore, the exception sent will not be complete, you'll lose the stack trace. If you really wish to do so, just throw like that:

```
catch(ex)
{
  throw;
}
```

Comment: I would add that Childmethod_2() shouldn't use a try-catch at all, and Childmethod_1() should use "throw;" after "Report(ex);" just like @Antonie says. Also it would be nice to read following set of articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on implementation of Report(ex) method. If it doesn't rethrow the exception, but only stored exception data into the DB, then all iterations of your loop will be executed regardless exceptions occurred. In this case you can simplify your code (look below). Note that in this case you should make sure that Report(ex) method can't throw other exceptions (for example accessing to the database).

```
void MainMethod()
{
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Childmethod_1();
    }
}

Childmethod_1()
{
    try
    {
        [Block of Code]
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Report(ex);
    }
}
```

On the other hand if Report(ex) rethrows exception after storing data into the DB, then the exception will be caught in the catch block of MainMethod and other iterations will not be executed. In this case you can't omit the try-catch block in MainMethod. However ChildMethod_2 is still redundant.